# Log-in Portlet Hook

Tags: authentication, liferay, hook

I hooked the login portlet to customize it's layout/design and it's working fine...

[image: Login Hook]

but when the user input is wrong/incorrect (authentication failed) the layout/design of my login hook is becomes like this...

[image: Authentication Failed]

I want to have **SAME LAYOUT** even if the authentication failed.
How will I achieve this?

Thank you in advance.

Here's my code in my **hook of login struts action**

```
public void processAction(
org.apache.struts.action.ActionMapping actionMapping,
org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm actionForm,
PortletConfig portletConfig, ActionRequest actionRequest,
ActionResponse actionResponse) throws Exception {

}

protected boolean isCheckMethodOnProcessAction() {
return _CHECK_METHOD_ON_PROCESS_ACTION;
}

protected void login(ThemeDisplay themeDisplay,
ActionRequest actionRequest, ActionResponse actionResponse)
throws Exception {

}
protected void postProcessAuthFailure(ActionRequest actionRequest,
ActionResponse actionResponse, StrutsPortletAction originalStrutsPortletAction, PortletConfig portletConfig) throws Exception {
ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay) actionRequest
.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);

PortletURL portleturl = PortletURLFactoryUtil.create(actionRequest,
"secondlogin_WAR_triumainportlet", themeDisplay.getPlid(),
PortletRequest.RENDER_PHASE);

portleturl.setParameter("saveLastPath", Boolean.FALSE.toString());
String redirect = ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest, "redirect");
if (Validator.isNotNull(redirect)) {
portleturl.setParameter("redirect", redirect);
}
else{
portleturl.setParameter("loginError", redirect);
}

portleturl.setWindowState(WindowState.MAXIMIZED);

actionResponse.sendRedirect(portleturl.toString());

originalStrutsPortletAction.processAction(originalStrutsPortletAction,
                portletConfig, actionRequest, actionResponse);

}

private static final boolean _CHECK_METHOD_ON_PROCESS_ACTION = false;

private static final Log _log = LogFactoryUtil.getLog(Sample.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to adapt your styling of the error messages.
If an error occurs, this and another html fragment will get displayed on the response page. They both have the same markup.

```
<div class="alert alert-error"> Authentification failed. Please try again</div>
```

So you would need to style those, or even the surrounding wrapper div. As I am not informed about HOW you changed the css, I can not give you any further or more detailed advise.

[EDIT]
After rereading your question: 
Maybe I did understand your question wrong. Is it possible, that you are referring to Layout of the Page itself? That would be related to the response rendering with maximized=true. I think you could modify this behaviour by overriding the StrutsAction.

[EDIT2]
According to your edit in the question ;)

Please try this:

```
portleturl.setWindowState(WindowState.NORMAL);
```

Comment: I tried editing the login struts action but no luck. I don't know how to achieve SAME LAYOUT just like the layout on my login hook.

Comment: I edited my question and posted my codes in login struts action. Thank you in advance. Best Regards!

Comment: i've tried this but no luck.

portleturl.setWindowState(WindowState.NORMAL);

Pls Help. Thank you in advance